# Dynamic color change of Navbar elements NextJS

Tags: typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

This is the code for a Navbar for a hotel site, I want to make the color of the Navbar elements dynamically change depending on the background above which the fixed Navbar is located, i.e. if, for example, the first screen is dark, the elements take the white color `#fff`, we scroll below, or switch to another page (`/lodge`) where the background is already white, and the Navbar elements should change color to a darker `#313131`, so as not to merge with the background color.

I hope for your help, I would like to know how such functionality can be implemented? Maybe there is some way to invert the colors depending on the background behind the navbar elements?

**[Codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/navbar-hotel-sandbox-63l7v7)**

```
'use client';

import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";

const Navbar = () => {

  return (
    <div className="fixed w-full backdrop-blur-sm z-10 lg:px-[100px] md:px-[70px] sm:px-[35px] xs:px-[15px]">
        <div className="border-b-[2px] border-[#313131]">
            <div className="lg:pb-5 lg:pt-7 md:pb-5 md:pt-6 sm:pt-5 sm:pb-4 xs:pt-10 xs:pb-[10px]">
                <div className="flex flex-row items-center">

                    {/* logo */}
                    <div className="relative lg:w-[146px] lg:h-[64px] md:w-[132px] md:h-[58px] sm:w-[90px] sm:h-[50px] xs:w-[68px] xs:h-[30px]">
                        <Link href="/">
                            <Image
                                src="/images/navbar/logo-b.svg" 
                                alt="logo-b" 
                                layout="fill"
                            />
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                    
                    {/* lodge */}
                    <div className="lg:text-[28px] md:text-[24px] lg:block md:block sm:hidden xs:hidden font-medium leading-normal uppercase text-[#313131] lg:pl-[610px] md:pl-[284px] lg:pr-[80px] md:pr-[80px]">
                        <Link href="/lodge">
                            LODGE
                        </Link>
                    </div>

                    {/* our blog */}
                    <div className="lg:text-[28px] md:text-[24px] md:block sm:hidden xs:hidden font-medium leading-normal uppercase text-[#313131]">
                        <Link href="/#ourblog">
                            OUR BLOG
                        </Link>
                    </div>

                    {/* num */}
                    <div className="flex flex-row items-center lg:gap-5 md:gap-5 sm:gap-3 lg:pl-[100px] md:pl-[80px] sm:pl-[162px]">
                        <div className="relative lg:w-[24px] lg:h-[24px] md:w-[24px] md:h-[24px] sm:w-[20px] sm:h-[20px] lg:block md:block sm:block xs:hidden">
                            <Image 
                                src="/images/navbar/tel-b.svg" 
                                alt="tel" 
                                layout="fill"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="lg:text-[28px] md:text-[24px] sm:text-[20px] font-medium leading-normal uppercase text-[#313131] lg:block md:block sm:block xs:hidden">
                            +57 (316) 893-1653
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    {/* lang switch */}
                    <div className="lg:text-[28px] md:text-[24px] sm:text-[20px] font-medium leading-normal uppercase text-[#313131] lg:pl-[100px] md:pl-[132px] sm:pl-[50px] xs:pl-[139px]">
                        <div className="flex flex-row items-center">
                            <div className="cursor-pointer underline">
                                EN
                            </div>
                            <div className="lg:px-4 md:px-[15px] sm:px-[10px] xs:px-[10px] cursor-default">
                                |
                            </div>
                            <div className="cursor-pointer">
                                ES
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="lg:hidden md:hidden sm:block xs:block sm:pl-[60px] xs:pl-[30px]">
                        <Image
                            className="cursor-pointer"
                            src="/images/navbar/burger_menu_b.svg"
                            alt="burger menu"
                            width={24}
                            height={24}                        
                        />

                        {/* <BurgerMenu onClose={() => setShowBurgerMenu(false)} /> */}
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar;
```

I tried to implement this through `useRouter` and `window.addEventListener` on the scroll (colors change down and up on the scroll by a certain number of px), but this method worked with a delay (when switching to another page the colors were updated not immediately, but after the scroll action) and I realized that this is not the best way, as it also adds work to the adaptive design.